# Jquery - How do I dynamically adjust height of iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying this code to adjust the height of an iframe to that of the browser window. I see `dochit` filling with the proper value, but it is not passing it to the iframe.  When I use a `<div>` tag in place of the iframe, it resizes fine.

```
$(window).resize(function()  {
    var dochit = $(document).height();
    $("#pmividcon").css("height", dochit);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a wrapper and then make the frame be 100% of it , check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLZAt/)

```
#wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
#myFrame {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.jquery.com" id="myFrame" />
</div>

    var dochit = $(document).height();
$("#wrapper1 ").css({
     "height": dochit + "px
 });
```