# Adjusting height of iframes in jQuery Masonry (YouTube embeds)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-masonry, masonry

Total noob here, trying to put together a jquery masonry page with a YouTube video embedded.

Problem is, the height of the video is not adjusting, and I can't figure out how to get the proportions right.

I've looked at the following links, but I can't figure out how to incorporate these ideas into my code.

[Jquery - How do I dynamically adjust height of iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745370/jquery-how-do-i-dynamically-adjust-height-of-iframe)
[Adjust Height of iFrame When New Content is Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334453/adjust-height-of-iframe-when-new-content-is-loaded)

My entire block of code below. You'll notice that the div adjusts fine for the image, but fails to adjust appropriately for the embedded YouTube video.

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Article Title</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    font: 1em/1.67 Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

img, iframe {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.title, .footer {
text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
margin: 0;
}

.title a {
display: inline-block;
padding: .75em 1.25em;
color: #888;
border: 2px solid #aaa;
margin: .25em 1em 1em;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-ms-border-radius: 3px;
-o-border-radius: 3px;
}

.title {
color: #666;
}

.title a:hover {
color: #666;
border-color: #888;
}

.footer {
font-size: .75em;
}

.footer, .footer a {
color: #888;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 1260px;
    }
}
</style>


<style>
body {
margin: 0;
}
.labs-header a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 1em 2em;
}
.labs-header,
.labs-header a {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.labs-header a:hover {
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.labs-header.dark,
.labs-header.dark a {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
.labs-header.dark a:hover {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<header class="labs-header">
</header>

<div class="demo-wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="title"><h1>Responsive CSS Masonry</h1></div>

<div class="masonry">
<div class="item">Hello, this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long sentence.</div>
<div class="item"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/c5nbLCuiGiU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="item">Hello!</div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://sites.psu.edu/siowfa14/wp-content/uploads/sites/13467/2014/10/female-red-eyed-tree-frog-tree-frogs-11755689-600-426.jpg"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. All I had to do was remove the following piece of code:

```
img, iframe {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;
}
```